# For Loop Logic Iteration Why not behaving Same ?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I have tried to Increasing Number By one Like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Count " + i);

        }
```

this logic Works fine.

but when i try to make it As user input for the series its not giving same out put from 0

See this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // System.out.println(scanner.hasNextInt());
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            // System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()));
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()); i++) {
                System.out.println("Count " + i);
            }
        }
```

its not giving out put by increasing element its giving if i input for example 12
Out Put:-

```
15
Count 0
```

Can any body can say why?

Comment: Don't call `next()` two times

Comment: Besides the calling `next()` twice, without knowing your input, it might be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()); i++) {
    System.out.println("Count " + i);
   } using single next also giving same input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `scanner.next()` twice.  The first time all you do is print it out, and then discard it.

Try putting it in a variable instead:

```
//this could use scanner.nextInt() instead
int limit = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()); 
System.out.println(limit);
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    //...
```

Comment: Actually the OP is potentially calling `scanner.next()` *lots* of times - once before the loop, and then once *per iteration* of the loop.

Comment: okey just trying using single this one for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()); i++) {
    System.out.println("Count " + i);
   } still same result.

Comment: @JonSkeet i think little i got it it will take number of numbers into the input isnt it if will give 15 it will take it as 1 right 0,1 isnt it ?

Comment: @Krishna: I didn't follow that comment *at all* but I suggest you review how a `for` loop works - the whole condition is evaluated on each iteration, so when the condition includes `Integer.parseInt(scanner.next())` it will try to read another token on each iteration...

Comment: @JonSkeet okey jon so i got it it will try to find every time new input isnt it? so its giving 0 in out put.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `scanner.next()` reads a new token, which you parse to int.

You have to store the first input and reuse it :

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // System.out.println(scanner.hasNextInt());
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int len = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.println("Count " + i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same thing i have done in this Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()); why its not working then.